# HP Proliant Servers doesn't boot OS ("boot logical drive is configured but is missing or offline" error)

Tags: hp-proliant, boot, operating-system, direct-attached-storage

I purchased a refurbished HP Proliant Server DL560 Gen8 in order to create my own home lab.

The most painful step was to get an Operating System properly working, doesn't matter what was the OS. I tried VMware Esxi, Red Hat, Windows, among others. I spent more than 16 hours researching (even here) and troubleshooting that matter.

The installation was succeeding, but after restarting the server, it was not booting up the OS.
Changing the boot sequence or method (UEFI/Legacy) was not the answer, neither using the HP Intelligent Provisioning for installation.

Answer (score 1):

Breathing and carefully looking for error messages during the booting process, the following caught my attention: "boot logical drive is configured but is missing or offline".
Below are the steps to solve the issue:

1. Start the server and wait until you see: “Press F8 to run option ROM configuration for Array utility”.
2. Press F8, you will see the Main Menu, select the last option “Select Boot Volume”.
3. Select “Direct attached storage”.
4. If you see “First logical drive 01” – select it.
5. Press F8 to save Logical Drive 01 as Boot Volume.
6. Press F8 to Exit and start with New Boot Volume.

After that, I'm happy and running an Esxi at my home lab.

Source: An old post at https://itkbs.wordpress.com/2015/07/06/hp-proliant-servers-boot-logical-drive-is-configured-but-is-missing-or-offline-error/